# UV Map or topology correction needed?

Tags: texturing

See screen captures for issue (below).

**Question:** In order to have the wood grain texture follow the frame direction without the oddness evident in the detail (image below), do I have to (1/2) or can I (3)...

1. Create a UV Map?
2. Correct something in the topology of the object?
3. Do something really simple (in the texture panel perhaps) that is eluding me right now?

**NOTE**: The object has been created via **Spin**.

Thanks, as ever, for the guidance - always appreciated...

[image: close-up showing issue with wood direction]
[image: Object with wood grain]

Comment: Most likely to create UV map. In *Mapping* section you use *UV*, so it tries to map the image accordingly; if you're fine with generated coordinates, use *Generated* or *Object* although for more control unwrap the mesh and use *UV*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a UV map, it is the best way in this case.

Simply select the front faces of your model in the 3D view and press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap, then select the back faces of your model and unwrap again.

Or select everything and press <kbd>U</kbd> to choose Smart UV Project.

Comment: Thanks for this - no easy way out - UV it is. I've given it a quick whirl and though daunting, got a reasonable result straight-off with 'Smart UV Project' - the faces in the resulting layout were separate and I could rotate and move them individually. Intuitive. Thanks for the heads-up on that. (U > Unwrap seemed to create something with faces that weren't separate so a level-up in knowledge I don't have right now. Skidaddled outta there for now)